# sampled_softmax_loss vs negative sampling

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, data-science, autoencoder

I am working on text autoencoder so want to use negative sampling for training our model. I want to know the difference between negative sampling and sampled softmax.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.tensorflow.org/extras/candidate_sampling.pdf

Accoring to tensorflow negative sampling relates to logistic loss while sampled softmax relates to softmax.

Both of them, at the core, pick a sample of negative examples to compute the loss on and update gradients.

For your model, use it if your output is very large (many classes) AND the regular loss is too slow to compute. If the output has few classes there's not much gain. If the training is fast anyway, why bother with approximations.